# set javadoc template for type in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

How to set the template for javadoc in `IntelliJ Idea`?
In Eclipse I can do it like this

[image]

But how to do that `Idea`?

Comment: @glytching I knew about that question but with it I still couldn't set the javadoc for class. Tobb's answer helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit javadoc template for classes (files):

- Open settings (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>).
- Select  `File and Code Templates` under `Editor`
- Select the `Includes` tab
- Edit `File Header`

See the description pane for examples of predefined variables.